# Problema en StoryBoard en Xcode 11

Tags: xcode

hice mi aplicación en iOS 12 con Xcode 10 y al actualizara a iOS 13 y Xcode 11 el storyboard me sale de esta manera, solo cuando utilizo un Navigation Controllers. Me podrían dar una mano. Gracias! 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. En tu storyboard debes seleccionar el Segue que muestra esa
   vista.
2. En el inspector a la derecha -> pestaña de Attributes ->
   Opción Kind
3. Seguramente tengas seleccionada la opción "Present
       Modally" o "Present as a popover"
4. Marca la opción **Show (e.g.
       Push)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto debería quedar solucionado y mostrarte la navegación sin vistas modales.

Si la solución anterior no funciona puedes probar a añadir el siguiente código dentro del **viewDidLoad** de tu ViewController:
Obj-C:

```
if (@available(iOS 13, *)){
    [self.navigationController setModalInPresentation:YES];
}
```

Swift:

```
if (@available(iOS 13, *)){
    self.navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
}
```

Comment: Buenas tardes agradezco tu respuesta pero ya verifique eso mismo y aun sigue saliendo la misma cosa

Answer (score -1):

La solución a este problema la respondí hace poco [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/311759/padding-top-en-uiwebview-con-swift/323861#323861). Sigue los pasos que indico ahí, abajo te dejo una pequeña explicación de porque pasa esto.

Si ya verificaste que los segues son de tipo **Push** y aun así persiste el problema, es porque tu root controller (vista inicial) no esta conectada a un `UINavigationController`. Entonces, una vista al no tener un navigation y querer hacer un push por default mostrará la nueva vista como si fuera un modal, utilizando un **Present**.