# Padding Top En UIwebview con Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uiwebview

Por favor su ayuda al momento de crear un segue entre 2 vistas, la primera es un login manual y la segunda vista contiene un UIwebview que al enlazar con segue me pone un padding automático que no puedo quitar adjunto foto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 1. En tu storyboard debes seleccionar el Segue que muestra esa vista. 2. En el inspector a la derecha -> pestaña de Attributes -> Opción Kind 3. Seguramente tengas seleccionada la opción "Present Modally" o "Present as a popover" 4. Marca la opción **Show (e.g. Push)**

Answer (score 1):

Ese "padding" que ves es la presentación predeterminada que tiene una vista modal en iOS 13, esto puede ocurrir por 2 cosas.

1. Que el tipo de navegación del Segue sea `Present Modally`, de ser así, solo debes cambiar el tipo a `Show (e.g. push)`.

   Seleccionas el Segue en tu Storyboard, a la derecha en la pestaña de Attributes del inspector buscas la opción Kind y seleccionas Show (e.g. push).
2. Otro factor que podría ocasionar este problema es que tu root controller (vista inicial) no esté conectado a un `UINavigationController`. Esto lo resuelves de la siguiente manera.

   Primero seleccionas tu `View Controller` inicial, en el menú superior buscas la opción Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller.